# What is the difference at such classes targeting with css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I want to target a `span` class element:

If I do like this, it doesn't have any effect:

```
ul#sponsors li span .spanelement {
}
```

But if I do like this:

```
ul#sponsors li span.spanelement {
}
```

It's working. What's the difference in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one:

```
ul#sponsors li span .spanelement { }
```

matches any element with `class="spanelement"`, but it must be inside the span (which is inside an li inside a ul with id="sponsors").

This one:

```
ul#sponsors li span.spanelement { }
```

matches the `<span class="spanelement">` itself (provided it's inside an li inside a ul with id="sponsors").

Answer (score 1):

the first selects an element with class `spanelement` inside your `span`s, the second selects `span`s with class `spanelement`

so the first will match `<p>` here, while the second will match the span itself:

```
<ul id="sponsors"><li><span class="spanelement"><p class="spanelement">SOMETHING</p></span></li>/<ul>
```

if there is nothing inside the span, or the elements inside do not have class `spanelement`, then the first query will match nothing

Answer (score 1):

Your second example has no space between span and spanelement.
This CSS Selector statement therefor targets the span **with** the class "spanelement".

Example:

```
<span class="spanelement">
```

Adding a space changes the selector so that it selects all tags with a `spanelement` class **INSIDE** a span.

Example:

```
<span>
<spanelement\>
</span>
```